# How to run load database command of pgloader in a terminal while migrating data?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, pgloader

I want to migrate data from SQLite to PostgreSQL and I decided to use [`pgloader`](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/sqlite.html) for that.

However, the instructions are so poor that I do not know how to execute this command:

```
load database
     from sqlite:///Users/dim/Downloads/lastfm_tags.db
     into postgresql:///tags

 with include drop, create tables, create indexes, reset sequences

  set work_mem to '16MB', maintenance_work_mem to '512 MB';
```

It throws an error that `load` command not found or if I run it with `pgloader load` it throws an error to check the available options with pgloader.

Answer (score 1):

The script you posted should be saved as file. Lets assume you save that as `lastfm_tags.load`.

Then you can run it as `pgloader lastfm_tags.load`